# Having layout issues

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

So I have a layout, everything is fine besides this annoying button.

My layout consists of three `Layouts`, one being the header. And the other two displaying time and date. But in the `CardView`, I wish to add a `Button` under the time (`TextView`). But for some reason, it keeps going to the left? I've tried dragging it around but it doesn't seem to work.

[image: My layout, with button being on left]

My question is, how can I make the `Button` lay itself under the `TextView`?

The code below is the layout -

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="Button" />

        <com.activelauncher.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="10:08 PM"
            android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />              
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change android:orientation to vertical

Comment: @TDMaster Lol I'm so stupid xD Thank you, it worked fine :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `android:orientation = "vertical"` in `LinearLayout`

and keep `Button` code after Your `com.activelauncher.MyTextView` control code.

Check the following code.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_card"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.activelauncher.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="10:08 PM"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card" >

        <com.activelauncher.MyTextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="10:08 PM"
            android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Button" />-
</FrameLayout>
```